# Create a sphere mesh, subtracted of a load of points using Geometry Nodes

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes

Calling all *nodes* geniuses.

I'm trying to subtract a load of points from a UV sphere of radius $R$. I'm seeking the end effect of something that looks like a planet cracked in two.

[image: This is how it looks when the geometry nodes are connected such]

[image: Yet when I connect them like this (which is how I think they should be connected in order to achieve a subtraction of the points from the sphere) the points disappear entirely (as expected) but the sphere surface remains perfectly unblemished.]

[image: This is my total node map.]

Please note I'm quite new to nodes, so small words plz and plenty of pictures 
Cheers!

ps.1 My next stage of the project is to create a variable number of random length lines $L$ that shoot radially out from the centre of this same model. These lines begin at radius $R_0, R_0>R$. I know blender doesn't work on spherical coords $(r,\theta,\phi)$ but these lines are to have random $\theta$ and $\phi$. If any node guru wants to take home fifty points for Gryffindoor, advice on how I could achieve that would be - and I can't stress this enough - *mega*.

ps.2 I'm aware my screenshots aren't the best resolution for the total map, so I've attached a link to the blender file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qJVkcr8ck-1uszXhdaUyrFvP1Gx521Ck/view?usp=sharing) should you want a closer look.

Comment: You have not defined what r, R, L, δL, θ and ϕ are.  It's probably possible to guess what those are, but why would you want to make people guess the problem before solving it? Why not define it exactly without uncertain terms? You should draw a diagram showing what they are so it is exact and clear.

Comment: You should ask it as a separate question, but you could distribute random points on faces of a sphere and the use those points to instance lines, taking the rotation of the points for instance rotation so they end up rotated in the direction of sphere face normals(so that's approximately as if the lines were going from the center of the sphere) https://i.imgur.com/wNrqGtx.png You could modify the sphere geometry if you need to limit where the lines appear somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do Boolean operations with a mesh and a bunch of points. Boolean operations are for volumes defined by surfaces and a bunch of points doesn't have volume. You could convert those points to a volume and then convert that volume to mesh:

[image]